# Помогите пожалуйста) Как можно сделать так чтоб в функцию GetResponse() именно в fetch можно было передавать любую ссылку

Tags: fetch

```js
  const actor = function(obj) {
    ul.innerHTML += `<li>${obj.name}</li>`     
  } 

async function getRespons(link) {
  let response = await fetch("https://ajax.test-danit.com/api/swapi/people/1");
  let content = await response.json();
  console.log(content);
  actor(content)
}
getRespons()
```

Answer (score 1):

Имеется в виду это?

```
await fetch(link);
```

и

```
getRespons('url1');
getRespons('url2');
getRespons('url3');
```